# Can BarLegend Tricks be set according to the function?

Tags: plotting, legending

I am using it like this . Now how to set barlegend numbers according to the c[x] value?

```
c[x_] := (1 - 0.01/x^2)/( 4 [Pi] Sqrt[(1 - 0.0005/x) (1 - x/20)] x);



b[x_] = x;

 Legended[Graphics[ Table[{Hue[c[i]/(9*c[6])], Circle[{0, 0}, b[i]]}, {i, 1, 6, 0.1}], ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True], BarLegend[{Hue[c[#]/(9*c[6])] &, {1, 6}}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c[x_] := (1 - 0.01/x^2)/(4 Pi Sqrt[(1 - 0.0005/x) (1 - x/20)] x);
b[x_] = x;
Legended[Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[c[i]/(9*c[6])], Circle[{0, 0}, b[i]]}, {i, 1, 6, 0.1}], 
  ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True], 
 BarLegend[{Table[Hue[c[7 - i]/(9*c[6])], {i, 6}], {c[6], c[1]}}, 
  LegendLabel -> "c(x)"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you are welcome!